# Get parameters values of hooked methods

Tags: android, xposed

With xposed it is possible to hook methods of an Android app. Is it also possible to get access to the parameter values of the hooked method?

Comment: Of course you can. Getting access to the method parameters and the return value is one of the main purpose of hooking. Please note that Xposed is best when you want to permanently change the behavior of your system respectively one app. Developing an Xposed module however requires some time as you have to reboot your device after every code change to the module. Hence nowadays you you just want to perform some  quick tests the [Frida](https://frida.re) may be faster and easier as it allows to change the hooking code while the app is running.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it also possible to hook more than one method per module?

Comment: Of course yes (Xposed & Frida). See for exampple for Xposed here: [source of some Xposed modules](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers&method=findAndHookMethod).

Comment: Ok. And is it possible to switch those modules on and off through an app? So instead of switching the modules on and of trough the Xposed settings.

Comment: No. As I said Xposed modules are designed to make permanent changes to the system. If you want to just modify an app while it is running use Frida.

Comment: I mean if it would be possible to outsource those switches?

Comment: You ca try to do so. But AFAIK a hook once installed in an app cannot be removed. Only by killing and restarting the app you could restart also the hooking (and then not install the hook).